# Force `setup.py` to use setuptools

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, distutils

I'm using this code:

```
code = 'import setuptools;__file__={0!r};execfile(__file__)'.format(os.path.join(path, 'setup.py'))
args = ['install', '--single-version-externally-managed']
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-c', code, args])
```

To execute a `setup.py` and install the package. The problem occurs when `setup.py` uses distutils instead of setuptools: --single-version-externally-managed is not recognized by distutils.

How can I force `setup.py` to use setuptools?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the wrong solution...

Comment: But I need to call `setup.py` from a Python script: I'm writing a package manager.

Comment: Why another package manager? We already have pip. Also keep in mind that setup.py is being phased out, nextgen distutils a.k.a. packaging uses setup.cfg instead.

Comment: I want to write a package manager better than pip, but this is Off-topic. As for distutils2 it will be included in Python 3.3.

Comment: IMHO a much better idea would be to help improve pip instead.

Comment: I tried but I don't like the way it is written. In my opinion it's too verbose (without offending anyone).

Comment: Have you opened a bug report to request that the verbosity be changed, or that there is a -q option to control it?  This sounds like a frivolous reason to start yet another installer.

Comment: Also, distutils2 will be available from PyPI for Python 2.4-3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is basically what pip does. Based on the code you wrote, you will be using setuptools' `setup` function because you've imported from setuptools. [Setuptools paves over Distutils' `setup` function in its `__init__.py`.](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/src/e7e25219049c/setuptools/__init__.py#cl-59) Therefore, it doesn't mater if the setup.py script imports distutils or not. Setuptools will always win...

If for some reason you still have issues while running your command. Try compiling the file before execution. `exec(compile(...))` rather than `execfile(...)`

In response to @jknair answer... I'd also discourage the use of ez_setup.py, because it's code duplication, has unexpected behavior and is often excluded during package distribution (which makes it hard for tools like pip to run the setup.py without an ImportError).